# ¿Cuál sería la sentencia SQL adecuada para este problema?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy desarrollando un software de inventarios basado en ingresos por lotes y mi problema radica en que manejo un saldo mínimo de productos y necesito que el sistema me alerte mostrando los productos que tengan la suma del saldo de todos los lotes relacionados menor o igual al saldo mínimo que tienen establecido.

Son dos tablas las involucradas: `item` y `registroIngreso`. `item` registra el saldo mínimo y en `registroIngreso` se registra cada ingreso por fechas, cada uno con una cantidad y en relación con cada ítem haciendo así los lotes y con la suma un saldo total.

Mi sentencia (simplificada para ustedes) va así por el momento:

```
select i.idItem,SUM(r.cantidad)
from item i 
inner join registroIngreso r on r.idItem=i.idItem
Where i.saldoMinimo>=(Select SUM (r.cantidad))
Group by r.cantidad
```

Tengo un producto con dos lotes, uno con saldo superior al mínimo y otro que cuyo saldo es menor y la sentencia me muestra el resultado del lote con menor saldo. Como que no realiza la suma.

Porfa si me pueden ayudar con la corrección adecuada...y perdonen si me paso algún detalle minúsculo, todavía ando de amateur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consulta actual tiene unos cuantos problemitas.  Uno de ellos es que tu subconsulta no tiene un `FROM`, y por causa de esto, tu consulta en realidad equivale a:

```
select i.idItem,SUM(r.cantidad)
from item i 
inner join registroIngreso r on r.idItem=i.idItem
Where i.saldoMinimo>=r.cantidad
Group by r.cantidad
```

... lo que explica porque la suma no te funciona.  Pero de todas maneras, la consulta sufre de otros problemas, uno de ellos siendo que tu expresión `GROUP BY` no parece correcta tampoco.

Mas bien, creo que la clave está en mover la condición a una expresión `HAVING`. Agregué también un `LEFT JOIN` + `COALESCE` para menejar correctamente la posibilidad de productos que no tengan ningún registro en la tabla `registroIngreso`, pero puedes omitir esta modificación si esta posibilidad nunca se dá:

```
select i.idItem, coalesce(sum(r.cantidad), 0)
  from item i
  left join registroIngreso r
    on r.idItem = i.idItem
 group by i.idItem, i.saldoMinimo
having coalesce(sum(r.cantidad), 0) <= i.saldoMinimo
```

Comment: No podía ser más perfecto con left join gracias!!